# How do I implement Edit for Modal box?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the edit feature of a recipe box where user can click on Edit within a recipe panel, see the pre-populated recipe title and ingredients and able to modify and save the changes to display. So far I have been able to display a list of recipes, add a new recipe and delete a recipe, but I'm still confused about how to implement the Edit feature.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {FormInput} from './components/form';
import {RecipeList} from './components/recipe_list';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap/lib';


function parseNewRecipe(){
  const name = document.getElementById("recipe_name").value;
  const ingredients = document.getElementById("ing").value.replace(/\s/g,'').split(",");
  this.state.recipes.push({
    name, ingredients
  });

  this.setState({
    recipes: this.state.recipes
  });
  this.toggleModal();
}


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes:[{name:'Pumpkin Pie',ingredients:['Pumpkin Puree','Condensed Milk','Egg','Pumpkin Spice Pie','Pie Crust']},
      {name:'Spaghetti',ingredients:['Noodle','Tomato Sauce','Meatballs']},
      {name:'Onion Pie',ingredients:['Onions','Pie Crust']}],
      isOpen: false,


    };
     this.deleteRecipe = this.deleteRecipe.bind(this);
     this.editRecipe = this.editRecipe.bind(this);


  }
  toggleModal= (event) => {
      this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  addNewRecipe(){
    parseNewRecipe.call(this);
  }

   deleteRecipe(key){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          recipes: prevState.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe !== key )
      }));
   }



   editRecipe(oldRecipe,newItem){
     this.toggleModal();

   }




   render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <header className="jumbotron">
            <h1>  Your Recipe Box </h1>
      </header>
      <RecipeList recipes = {this.state.recipes} deleteRecipe={this.deleteRecipe} editRecipe={this.editRecipe}/>
      <Button onClick = {this.toggleModal} bsStyle="primary"> Add Recipe </Button>
      <FormInput ref = "input" show={this.state.isOpen} onClose={this.toggleModal} onAddRecipe={this.addNewRecipe.bind(this)
      } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap/lib';
import {Form, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Button} from 'react-bootstrap/lib';


function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id}>
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
export class FormInput extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={editing: false};
    }


    render(){

        if(!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }
        return(
            <div className="static-modal" >
                <Modal.Dialog>
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>Add Recipe</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Form>
                            <FieldGroup
                                id="recipe_name"
                                type="text"
                                label="Recipe Name"
                                placeholder="Enter Recipe Name"/>
                             <FormGroup id="formControlsTextarea">
                                <ControlLabel>Ingredients</ControlLabel>
                                <FormControl id = "ing" value = {this.props.ingredients} componentClass="textarea" placeholder="Enter Ingredients, separated, by commas" />
                            </FormGroup>

                        </Form>
                    </Modal.Body>

                    <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
                    <Button onClick ={this.props.onAddRecipe} bsStyle="primary">Save Changes</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal.Dialog>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the id from the recipe your editing to fetch the recipe data and load it into the form state. You didn't post code for `<FormInput/>`, so I'm not sure how your data is being managed.

Comment: I just posted the FormInput code

Comment: Hmm, so what you should be doing is using state to manage the form data. What it looks like you're doing is using vanilla js to scrape the values off the inputs. That's going to make it much harder for you. I would suggest converting your input into [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) that read from state. Then, all you would need to do is populate state with the existing recipe values. In your current approach, you will need to use vanilla js to set the values of your inputs based on the recipe data you are trying to edit.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific about what state should i set in the FormInput?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components Take a look at the docs for an example. Each form field should be bound to a piece of state (or even a prop).

Comment: cool I fixed it now. Could you elaborate a little more about what you meant by using the id of the recipe to fetch and load it in the form state? Thank you`

Comment: Do I do that in the app parent component, and pass it down to FormInput?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to store the id of the recipe the user clicks on to edit. Then you need to pass the data for that recipe to your FormInput to pre-populate your form fields.